# I need to calculate the molecular weight of protein fragments and put those values in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append, biopython

I'm using Biopython to calculate the fragment weights.
This is my code so far

```
sequences4 = SeqIO.parse('/content/short_protein_fragments.fasta', 'fasta')
seq_list4 = list(sequences4)

def fragment_weights(fragments):
    for i in fragments:                                             
        fragment_weights = 0.0    
        nums = []                                                   
        for aa in i.seq:                                           
          fragment_weights += SeqUtils.molecular_weight(aa, "protein")
        nums.append(round(fragment_weights, 2))
        print(nums)

fragment_weights(seq_list4)
```

I would expect an output like this:

```
[3611.86, 2269.63, 469.53, 556.56, 1198.41, 2609.88, 547.69, 1976.23, 2306.48, 938.01, 1613.87, 789.87, 737.75, 2498.71, 2064.25, 1184.39, 1671.87]
```

But rather it prints the values like this:

```
[3611.86]
[2269.63]
[469.53]
#and so on until the last value.
```

This piece of code needs to be used in a larger function, so the list of numbers needs to be "remembered" throughout the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each run of the loop, you are defining empty list `nums`, then appending one value and printing it. Next run, the same: define empty list, append one value, print.

Try this: list is defined before the loop, then append values in the loop, then print out of the loop. (Beware the indentation).

```
sequences4 = SeqIO.parse('/content/short_protein_fragments.fasta', 'fasta')
seq_list4 = list(sequences4)

def fragment_weights(fragments):
    nums = []  
    for i in fragments:                                             
        fragment_weights = 0.0                                                             
        for aa in i.seq:                                           
          fragment_weights += SeqUtils.molecular_weight(aa, "protein")
        nums.append(round(fragment_weights, 2))
    print(nums)

fragment_weights(seq_list4)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working like I wanted now.